# KeyBy vs GroupBy in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

What are the similarities and differences of KeyBy and GroupBy in Flink? If one is using the Table/SQL API in a Table only program is GroupBy equivalent to KeyBy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The streaming GroupBy in the Table/SQL API is the keyBy from the DataStream API.

Answer (score 1):

KeyBy is used for Streams data(incase of keyed Streams) and GroupBy is used for Data set API for Batch Processing.